# Using Crystal Report to show all data from a specific field from DataTable source

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I am coding a C# program that will print a shipping label. I have managed to query database from SQL and set up the datatable in C# with all correct data. Now I have link the datatable to Crystal report and design lay out, but I am facing one problem. I want the label to show all items in datatable continuously.

For example, correct way of showing data

[image: Correct way of showing data]

But after testing my label is this wrong

[image: Wrong]

The crystal report know there are 2 data in my field and process to separate them into 2 different reports.  I know that I would probably need to use loop, but I have no experience working with Crystal Report before.

Please any help is more than welcome. Thank you

Edit: What I have done is place a subreport in my main page[subreport](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qR2sy.png)
Then in the subreport I suppress all other section and place datafield in detail [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6W83M.png)
And then I managed to get the result I wanted [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F6XKa.png)

**Edit 2:** I have managed to completely solve my program by changing the layout of my crystal report. Before I put every data in detail section and suppress all other field, with obviously went wrong. I have try to solve it by placing the SKUs data in subreport but then it created new problem, as page 2 of subreport can not be shown on main report page, without complex condition and formula of cources.
Now what I have done is to the information field e.g: address, name, phone number of receiver into page header, and the information about: order code, print date in page footer as this field is the same no matter what.
Then I place 3 field needed to show on the same page SKU, quantity and weight in detail, create group for SKU, quantity and weight. Check group expert settings and select keep group together. Then go to Detail section expert and select layout, the detail width keep the same as your page width, the detail height will be the height of one single data line. And finally I get the result I wanted. I hope if someone face the same problem will now have a solution.
[Detail section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ttsae.png)
[Detail layout settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Cy1A.png) Note that I use A6 paper 10.4x14.8

Comment: You can place a table in your report and display tabular data in it.

Comment: It seems as though you already have some code, which is not working.  Might you please [edit] your question to share it?  It's more likely that we will be able to help you if we know where you are stuck.  See [ask]: *Help others reproduce the problem... if your problem is with code you've written, you should include some... Include just enough code to allow others to reproduce the problem.*

Comment: Thank you for comments, I have now manage to show a list of all items by using subreport and then place data field in detail section. But now I am facing another small problem, as crystal report count the number of rows in my datatable and proceed to print as many reports. I am currently trying to fix this situation. I will edit my question.